# Dictionary to table in PHP and HTML and sort number

Tags: php, html, dictionary, html-table

I have a "dictionary" that I got from my MySQL table ( string from MySQL) :

```
$MyInitialData={"Siberian husky dog": 0.763, "gnawing mammal": 0.736, "azure color": 0.976, "lapin rabbit": 0.715, "rabbit": 0.726, "animal": 0.932, "mammal": 0.736, "domestic animal": 0.849, "malamute dog": 0.53, "dog": 0.848}
```

I would like to display it this way in my HTML page using PHP code:

[image]

the difficulties are the transformation from "dictionary" to a table and sorting the data in order from the highest value to the lowest.

**EDIT:** as requested below, here is how I get the data from My DB:

```
<?=$dbContent = str_ireplace($keyword,'<b>'.$keyword.'</b>',$search_data['meta_description']); ?></p>
```

I do not have hands on the MySQL table. I receive it and have to sort it myself. 
And yes, I also asking how to display it on HTML using a recursive formula/code ( going thru the table )

I want to avoid this style:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>My Data :</th>
    <th>My Values</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>azure color</td>
    <td>0.976</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>animal</td>
    <td>0.932</td>
  </tr>
  etc...
</table>
```

And do something with iterations based on the size of my dictionary. 
What is more, I do not know the exact number of row each table may would be

Comment: Show us how do you perform the query in your code.

Comment: What's about `asort` ?

Comment: Why don't you get it in descending order straight from the MySQL table? `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY myvalues DESC`

Comment: Show us all the code, or at least the query

Comment: What specifically are you asking?  How to sort an array?  How to display data on a page?  Something else?

Comment: The question is not tagged with "MySQL" on purpose to avoid response using MySQL queries

Comment: How does your data look like? Your $MyInitialData looks like it is upposed to be a JSON object but no valid PHP. Do you convert this to an array or like? If so I could give you some code to generate your table in HTML.

Comment: @Fuzzzzel : This is it  ! :) . I actually need to convert but I do not know how to..

Comment: According to the documentation http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php you need to do something like: $myData = json_decode($MyInitialData, true); Then you have an array you can work with.

Comment: Thanks. And How would be the iteration thru my new array ( to update the table) ?